# Updating nested models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested, nested-forms

I have an app where there's a model Animal which has many Packages. I'm trying to create a form where the :true_weight attribute of a subset of the packages associated with a particular animal can be updated. This form is in a custom url/action (not show/new/edit or whatever). I feel like I've done most of it right, but it's just not updating the packages. I'll put my (abbreviated) code below and then explain what has and hasn't been working. Pretty stumped by this:

package.rb

```
attr_accessible :true_weight # And irrelevant others
belongs_to :animal
```

animal.rb

```
attr_accessible :finalized, :name # And irrelevant others
has_many :packages
accepts_nested_attributes_for :packages
```

routes.rb

```
match '/animals/:animal_id/log' => "animals#log"
```

animals/log.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@animal) do |f| %> 

<div style="width: 200px">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

    # This produces the subset of packages I want to be able to edit. It's an array
    # of arrays, so that each render produces a separate table made from one of the 
    # inner arrays.
<% @animal.packages_for_log.each do |bundle| %> 
    <%= render partial: 'package_bundle', locals: {:bundle => bundle} %><br>
<% end %>

<h4>And then you'd allow addition of extra packages here.</h4>

<%= f.submit "Submit Animal Log", :class => "btn image-button right" %>

<% end %>
```

_package_bundle.html.erb

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>Label</th>
            <th>True Weight></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% bundle.each do |package| %> <!-- Produces for each "bundle" the list of identical packages -->
            <%= fields_for package do |p| %>
                <% if package.order.user %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%= package.name %></td>
                        <td><%= package.line.processed_notes %></td>
                        <td><%= "#{package.order.user.name.first(3).upcase}-#{package.id}" %></td>
                        <% if !package.true_weight %>
                            <td colspan=1><%= p.text_field :true_weight %></td
                        <% else %>
                            <td><%= package.true_weight.round(0) %>lb</td>

                        <% end %>  
                    </tr>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>   
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

animals_controller.rb (log is an animal action/view)

```
def log
    @animal = Animal.find(params[:animal_id])

    if @animal.update_attributes(params[:animal])
      puts "Inside If Block"
      @animal.toggle!(:finalized)
    else
      # I don't know about this. I wanted to redirect to the updated log page, with a flash
      # but when I last tried that, it had some recursive error, or would update without my 
      # submitting.
      render action: "log"
    end

  end
```

So. What is working:

1. The if block in my animals controller is being accessed. But it looks like it's possibly being accessed BEFORE I hit submit on my log page. (I searched for and found that puts line in the server logs). May just be misreading it.
2. The form elements look right. I get a whole bunch of text boxes in the right places, and the information about each package that is being printed to the page in the table next to the text fields is correct.
3. If I fill in Animal Name attribute at the top of the form, that attribute (of the animal) IS updated.

What isn't working:

1. When I submit, it redirects me to the animal show page (!?!?), with the flash that's shown after the regular update action.
2. The @animal.toggle!(:finalized) action doesn't seem to do anything. Maybe, given 1 above, that boolean is being toggled twice? Back and forth?
3. The big one -- it doesn't update my packages, at all.

Any ideas what's going on here, or what I need to add? I'm really confused about what I'm not doing right.

Thanks!

EDIT -- Per request, adding the code for my packages_for_log method (in the animal.rb file)

```
def packages_for_log 
    master = []
    self.packages.each do |p|
      if p.sold

        # The master has sublists
        if master.any?
          counter = 0

          # Check for matching list. Add if found.
          master.each do |list|
            if p.notes == list.first.notes && p.type == list.first.type
              list << p
              counter += 1 # Don't create list is appropriate one found.
            end
          end
          if counter == 0
            master << [p] if counter == 0 # Add as new list if list doesn't yet exist.
          end
        else # If master is empty, add the package to a new sub-list.
            master << [p]
        end

      end

    end
    master.sort
  end
```

Basically, packages have types and notes. I want the log to create a separate table for each package type/note. So I create an array, and then populate it with arrays where all the packages share the same type/notes. (First, I make sure they're all sold. I don't want the log page to show unsold packages.)

Comment: There's a lot going on here -- there may be routing issues, sort of a funky thing to do `update_attributes` then `toggle!` which does a SQL update on the same record twice, and not updating packages ... something (perhaps just not shown here has to create the association and then save it.  This is a non-standard way to do a pretty typical thing: save nested forms -- you might want to google around for the usual way to do this, get that working and then decide if you need to get fancy.

Comment: Yeah. Looked at the RailsCast on nested models, but I can't see what I'm doing that's different that would stop it from working. The toggle thing I suppose I could just add to a hidden field, but that's sort of peripheral. My real problem is figuring out why the packages aren't being updated. Any idea what's up with that, or where the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here:

```
<%= form_for(@animal) do |f| %>
```

Default with this definition, Rails will create or update a record with information on form, so when you submit form, and rails check this is not a new record, it performed `update` action, not `log` action. Try change to this :

```
<%= form_for(@animal), :url => { :action => "log" }  do |f| %>
```

and submit form again and check if it works.

**Edit:** You're not used `fields_for` in:

```
<% @animal.packages_for_log.each do |bundle| %> 
  <%= render partial: 'package_bundle', locals: {:bundle => bundle} %><br>
<% end %>
```

Add `fields_for` and try again:

```
<%= fields_for @animal.packages_for_log.each do |bundle| %> 
  <%= render partial: 'package_bundle', locals: {:bundle => bundle} %><br>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just gave that a try (though I had to expand the parentheses around the :url assignment). It fixed the redirect problem, but, alas, the packages remain un-updated.

Comment: see my edited answer and try it. if you can you should put the code of `packages_for_log`, i actually don't understand what it do.

Comment: Oh. OK. I'll paste the code. It's basically just a method for creating the list of the packages I want to update. Let me try your edit.

Comment: Wait. SHOULD I do fields_for animal again? Those fields are for the PACKAGES associated with the animal, not the animal itself. That's why (in my _package_bundle file) I have "fields_for package".

Comment: oh, i see, but why you have two loop here? You looped `<% @animal.packages_for_log.each do |bundle| %>` to get one by one package, and then you continues loop `<% bundle.each do |package| %>`, what `package` will get when `bundle` just a element of an array of `packages_for_log`? and you loop `fields_for` too. If you want to loop, the only things you will loop are fields of your nested model, means package's attribute, as in my answer.

Comment: Bundle is actually a variable representing a group of packages. So I loop through that to make a line for each package.

Comment: You were right. That second loop was unnecessary. Interesting. At any rate, my answer is really simple. I just left off the "f" before the "fields_for package", basically.